# How to get selected item name form Context menu in android

Tags: android

I am using the android List View in my activity ...

Now i need get the name for the item selected from the list...

here's my code for menu create

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
       super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);         


     MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu); //select layout which should pop up in context menu

     menu.add("Delete");
     menu.add("Rename");

}
```

what i need is the way to get the list view selected item's name in the following function which captures the click on Context menu.

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{

     super.onContextItemSelected(item);


    if(item.getTitle()=="Delete"){
       //slected item's name in string varible here??
    }
    if(item.getTitle()=="Rename"){
            //slected item's name in string varible here??
    }
    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to get the itemId use this:

```
AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
```

you can get the id of an item via

```
info.id
```

If you want to receive the name, you can also use to `info.position` to get the position of the item in the list. With the position you can get the item from the listView to get the name of the item

Answer (score 1):

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo itemInfo = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        int itemId = itemInfo.position;
// Implements our logic

```
    if (item.getTitle()=="Add") {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Item id [" + itemId + "]", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
    return true;

}
```

Comment: The correct if condition is item.getTitle().equals("Add")